# Mysql explode impode

Tags: mysql

Всем добрый день.
Имеется поле в таблице, которые содержит записи вида:

10,12,415

т.е. числа через запятую. Необходимо запросом вывести строку вида:

(10)(12)(415)

т.е. числа обернуть в скобки и запятые убрать.
На php можно было поделить строку в массив с помощью explode и после с помощью implode склеить все обратно в строку как нужно.
Может у кого есть идея как это сделать запросом select в mysql?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать через с помощью функций CONCAT и REPLACE:

SELECT CONCAT('(', REPLACE(field, ',', ')('), ')') FROM table

Comment: Интересное решение, чет даже не додумался до такого, сейчас опробую. Спасибо))